# Making Android filepaths uniform

Tags: android, file, android-studio, filepath

I have three segments of code: one that sets the original filepath of the file, one that is used in renaming the file, and one that is used to match the file so that the file (audio recording) can be played.

My problem is that, to the best of my knowledge & what I have been able to find out online, I need "file://" before the rest of the filepath when I am renaming it...otherwise the MediaPlayer throws up exceptions when I try to do the playback. After much searching, I have not come up with a good way to make them uniform so that the "matcher" code can work on all the files. My best guess is that it would be ideal if I could find a way to not have to use "file://" before the rest of the filepath.

1) Code that sets original filepath:

```
public void setFileNameAndPath(){
    int count = 0;
    File f;
   do{
        count++;

        mFileName = getString(R.string.default_file_name)
                + " #" + (mDatabase.getCount() + count) + ".mp4";
        mFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFilePath += "/SoundRecorder/" + mFileName;

        f = new File(mFilePath);
    }while (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory());
}
```

2) Renaming the filepath:

```
public void rename(int position, String name) {
    //rename a file

    String mFilePath = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFilePath += "/SoundRecorder/" + name;
    File f = new File(mFilePath);

    if (f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) {
        //file name is not unique, cannot rename file.
        Toast.makeText(mContext,
                String.format(mContext.getString(R.string.toast_file_exists), name),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } else {
        //file name is unique, rename file
        File oldFilePath = new File(getItem(position).getFilePath());
        oldFilePath.renameTo(f);
        mDatabase.renameItem(getItem(position), name);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
}
```

3) Matching the file:

```
Intent iin = getIntent();
Bundle b = iin.getExtras();
newString = (String) b.get("filename");
mFilePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
mFilePath += "/SoundRecorder/" + newString;
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you have with `file://`? And even if you need it to the best of your knowledge, have you tried it without? `file://` is rarely needed since everything starting with `/` is a plain file and most code will know that.

Comment: I have to use file:// to allow playback of each recording. I have tried without it..it doesn't play but has the pause button, then when i push pause it is at the end of the recording, then when i press play, the app crashes (normally it just plays again). I found that solution on a stackoverflow answer that I wasn't able to find again.

The problem is that one set of recordings begin with "file://" and the other doesn't, I'm sending the end of the name as putExtra, and I can only have one filepath string.

Comment: what about adding `file://` in case the path starts with `/`?` Then you everything is the same

Comment: Then it fails with a illegalstateexception.

Comment: Tbh, your main problem seems to be a messy code base rather then file:// or no file://  - I still don't see where / why you can't solve the problem with simple string operations, like checking for file://, then adding or removing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think file:// is the URI of the file and it's useful for example in a mediaplayer where the resource can exists on local storage (file://) or over internet (http://)

To "convert" string to URI use

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com");
```

And to "convert" URI to file use

```
File file = new File(uri.getPath());
```

Comment: Can you explain how I'm supposed to use that with my situation?

Comment: You write "My best guess is that it would be ideal if I could find a way to not have to use "file://" before the rest of the filepath" you shouldn't use the file:// prefix (URI) for renaming file, just use the filepath. 
But if you want to get the URI (file://) because it's required for your mediaplayer use `Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(filepath);`

Comment: if it doesn't answer your question please update your question because I don't understand exactly what you want...